# Group on newly created files show as 100

Tags: linux, permissions, suse

I ran

```
id -g <username>
id -gn <username>
```

My primary group is `users` which has group ID of 1000.

When I create a directory or a file, the group on it shows as 100. 
Same when I copy a file without the -a option. 
I ran

```
"grep "100" /etc/groups
```

the only match I got was

> users:x:1000:

I know 100 is the default ID for the users group, but on this system it appears to be 1000.

Here is a partial listing from `ls -la`

```
-rw-------  1 ventsyv   100        36684 2016-11-11 15:59 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 ventsyv   100           55 2016-11-03 03:28 .bashrc
```

Can someone explain what's going on?

Edit: The authentication is done through LDAP so I suspect it's a LDAP vs local group issue.
Distro is Suse Server 11.

Comment: How do you know the file or directory listing isn't just being truncated? Can you show output of an `ls -ln` command on a recently-created file or directory?

Comment: Also, you might have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319729/recommended-gid-for-users-group-in-linux-100-or-1000 for some background information on the issue. What distribution of Linux are you using?

Comment: Distro is Suse 11

Comment: Can you run `ls -ld` on the directory in which you're attempting to create new files/folders?

Comment: @jayhendren It's my home dir: drwxr-xr-x 6 ventsyv 100 760 2016-11-11 16:17

Comment: What does `getent passwd ventsyv` show?  It will show your account infromation from whichever source is found first accorning to `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.  The GID shown in the 3rd field will be your default group, and I would expect that it is 100.

Comment: The fact that the GID on your files is a GID not a name says there is no group with that GID in `/etc/group` or LDAP.

Comment: @MikeA yes, there is no group with GID of 100 in /etc/group. The "users" group has GID of 1000 in /etc/groups ventsyv:x:1330125811:1000::/homes/ventsyv:/bin/tcsh

Comment: Post output of `getent passwd ventsyv`.  Post output of `grep -E 'passwd|group' /etc/nsswitch.conf`.